# SYBASE how to get two top salary from table employee and salary using join

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, sybase

I have two tables

```
 employee
 --------- 
 ID, 
 first_name, 
 last_name

 salary 
 ------ 
 id, 
 first_name, 
 last_name,  
 salary
```

How can I get two highest salary using join tables?

Comment: Nobody knows how to solve the problem?

Comment: Sorry, incorrect tables.employee with ID, first_name, last_name.Salary table has just id and salary. Please help. I need to solve this problem with join only

Comment: First, what have you tried?  Second, this is a very basic problem, so most of us assume that you really haven't given it much effort.   You will have to do a join, along with a subquery.

Comment: employee    
 ---------     
 ID,     
 first_name,     
 last_name        

 salary     
 ------     
 id,      
 salary

Comment: That information is already in the question...not really a helpful comment.

Comment: It is OK, probably this way:       select s.salary from salary s    
                                                 left outer join employee e    
                                                 on s.id=e.id     
                                                 where s.salary = (select top 2 m.salary from salary m)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `id` in the `salary` table is a foreign key that references the `id` column in the `employee` table. And assuming that `id` is unique in the `employee` table and `salary` table.  (Those are pretty big assumptions, but absent actual table definitions, we're just guessing.)

And assuming that `salary` is numeric datatype, and that by "top two" you mean you want the largest values of salary, and that you only want to return one column (salary) in the resultset... (again, very big assumptions, but without a more detailed specification, we're just left guessing...)

Then something like this might work for you:

```
SELECT TOP 2 s.salary
  FROM salary s
  JOIN employee e
    ON e.ID = s.id
 ORDER BY s.salary DESC
```

As an alternative, I think you could omit the `TOP 2` and execute a separate `set rowcount 2` before you run the query.

It's not at all clear (from your question) what you have tried, the behavior you observed, or why you need a JOIN (if you're only interested in `salary`).

---

As another more bizarre alternative, if you have to use `JOIN`, and you don't want to include the `employee` table in the query... it's possible to do a self join and get a "count" of the number of rows that have a "higher" salary. (to take into account the possibility that `salary` is not unique, we'll consider the `id` column as the tie-breaker, if two (or more) rows have the same salary.

```
 SELECT s.salary
   FROM salary s
   LEFT  
   JOIN salary t
     ON t.salary >= s.salary
    AND (t.salary > s.salary OR t.id > s.id)
 GROUP BY s.id
HAVING COUNT(t.id) < 2
```

(If there are three or more rows with the same "highest" value of `salary`, only two rows will be returned, with the same value of `salary`.)